# Is it possible to apply a CSS filter to an image, but not to the background-color?

Tags: css, svg-filters

Firstly, is it possible (see question title) to do *without* any weird workaround magic?

Otherwise, what is the best workaround?

HTML:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(500%);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I do *not* want the background-color to be affected by the filter.  Only the image.  The solution should *not* be specific to the brightness filter, but should work for any filter.

Comment: What purpose is the background-color serving?  Could you use a container instead, like this fiddle (crudely) demonstrates?  https://jsfiddle.net/8bouk52j/1/

Comment: The image has parts that are translucent / transparent, and the background color changes depending on what the user clicks, etc.  I'm guessing that will be the best workaround, but I'm secretly hoping there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS filter referencing a SVG filter and add your background color to the filter using a separate class. Something like:

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: url(#brightoverback);
  filter: url(#brightoverback);
}

#bck-color {
  flood-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
        <svg width="0px" height="0px">
          <defs>
          <filter id="brightoverback" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="5 0 0 0 0   0 5 0 0 0   0 0 5 0 0  0 0 0 1 0" result="bright-image"/>
         <feFlood id="bck-color" result="blue-field"/>
        <feComposite operator="over" in="bright-image" in2="blue-field"/>
        </filter>
            </defs>
    </svg>


    <img height="400" width="800" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6ZTUSkeNUHk/U5sKaUJ02xI/AAAAAAAARg8/oHbz-L-t2TM/s1600/PNG+Water+Ripple+(4).png">
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work.  Where exactly in the HTML file does the SVG filter belong? Should it be enclosed in an `<svg>` tag?  Do I need to worry about load order?

Comment: yes a filter tag needs to be wrapped in an svg (can set the size of the svg to 0 width and height) and a defs tag. It should load before you use it. There are literally thousands of examples of how to use a filter tag on the internets